# How to interpret a form in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

say, I have this:

```
var html = '<form><input type="text" value="v" name="nnn"></form>';
```

now I want to "unserialize" this, I mean to get an object/array with the key `nnn` and the value `v`. So,

```
{
    nnn: 'v',
    otherInputField: 'itsValue'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `serializeArray`

```
var html = '<form><input type="text" value="v" name="nnn"></form>';
$(html).serializeArray();
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bgf7v02z/1/)

If it absolutely must be a pure object, you can process the array into an object like

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

[Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery)